# has_one WITHOUT nested attributes. possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, called User.

And User can optionally connect ONE account to external resource.

Currently I made everything using `has_many`. Regular NEW/CREATE action.
But I don't want him to `have_many` accounts of that external resource.

Is that possible?
For now the only option I saw was to build_external_resource on signup, and then permit params at application controller & submit everything into Devise controller. Pretty ugly.

Just want him NOT have that reconrd when he signs up, but be able to set up one when he likes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is rather ambiguous, I'd look at this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :resource

    before_create :build_resource if Proc.new { |a| a.resource_id.present? }
end

#app/models/resource.rb
Class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Your schemas would look like this:

```
users
id | name | created_at | updated_at

resources
id | user_id | information | other | attributes | created_at | updated_at
```

This would allow you to set the resource in on the user `new` / `create` pages *if* you wanted to. However, if you didn't set the `resource_id` attribute, it would not be created

Is this what you're looking for?